# how to scale up/down a graph while getting different range of numbers?

Tags: java, swing, graph

I've created a graph using java and swing but it is only good for showing positive numbers and some negative numbers less than -14 the idea that I've used was :

- create a box
- add my X and Y axis label
- get an array of numbers
- get max number for indicating the max number in the array
- create an scale using following code :

```
double scale = (double)(height - 2*borderSpace)/getMax();
```

and then plot my line graph , above solutions is perfect for positive values for negative values I did a trick

```
int height2 = getHeight() - getHeight()/2;
double scale = (double)(height2 - 2*borderSpace)/getMax();
```

which is only works till -14 not less than that.

for drawing lines I use this code

```
//borderspace = 20
double xInc = (double)(width - 2*borderSpace)/(data.length-1);
        double scale = (double)(height - 2*borderSpace)/getMax();
        g2.setPaint(Color.green.darker());
        for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length-1; i++) {
            double x1 = borderSpace + i*xInc;
            double y1 = height - borderSpace - scale*data[i];

            double x2 = borderSpace + (i+1)*xInc;
            double y2 = height - borderSpace - scale*data[i+1];
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
        }
```

I want to have the box but Y axis should be on the left side( I don't want to change the Y axis place) and I just want to change the place X axis in case of having negative numbers 
for making it more clarify you can have a look at this picture :

[image]

Comment: Sorry your question is very unclear.  You haven't posted any code that can be tested.

Comment: I added my drawing line method too

Comment: again, not a piece of code that can be tested.  also this is starting to feel like homework, you have basic calculation redundancies like `height2 = getHeight() - getHeight()/2` ; since `height2 = getHeight() / 2` suffices ... In any event, you are not using height2 anywhere in your drawing method... Or if you are it's not clear how.

Comment: please read my question carefully or else thanks for not helping me! I have mentioned above that for drawing negative lines I use height2 not for all situations.

Comment: I read that, something told me that problem(s) came from another code

Comment: @austinpowers AND you have said that your problem is with that negative code, however you don't share that code. Anyone here would be happy to help, that's why we read the questions, but if you don't supply enough information no one can help, and just getting snippy about it is simply rude. since you aren't really paying anyone here.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to create your graphs rather than trying to brew your own solution from scratch.

Comment: I don't want to use any sort of third party solution